# Remove duplicates of array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I was just going through these questions for PHP and got stuck at one of them. The question is:

> You have a PHP 1 dimensional array. Please write a PHP function that
> takes 1 array as its parameter and returns an array. The function must
> delete values in the input array that shows up 3 times or more?
>
> For example, if you give the function
>
> array(1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1, 9)`the function will return`array(1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 9)

I was able to check if they are repeating themselves but I apply it to the array I am getting as input.

```
function removeDuplicate($array){
    $result = array_count_values( $array );
    $values = implode(" ",  array_values($result));
    echo $values . "<br>";  
}

$qArray = array(1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1, 9);
removeDuplicate($qArray);
```

One more thing, we cannot use `array_unique` because it includes the value which is repeated and in question we totally remove them from the current array.

Comment: Shows up 3 times or more consecutively or anywhere in the array?

Comment: Do `$values = array_filter($values, function($value) { return $value <= 3; })` after your `array_count_values()`. but your function then wants to return `array_keys($values)`

Comment: You haven't replied to any of the answers; are we even understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, Jack I think some of them did. I got my problem already solved though. I will mark the correct answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value may not appear 3+ times anywhere in the array:

```
$array = array(1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1, 9);

// create array indexed by the numbers to remove    
$remove = array_filter(array_count_values($array), function($value) {
    return $value >= 3;
});

// filter the original array
$results = array_values(array_filter($array, function($value) use ($remove) {
    return !array_key_exists($value, $remove);
}));
```

If values may not appear 3+ times consecutively:

```
$results = [];
for ($i = 0, $n = count($array); $i != $n;) {
    $p = $i++;
    // find repeated characters
    while ($i != $n && $array[$p] === $array[$i]) {
        ++$i;
    }

    if ($i - $p < 3) {
        // add to results
        $results += array_fill(count($results), $i - $p, $array[$p]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
function removeDuplicate($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $new[$val] ++;
        if ($new[$val] >= 3)
            unset($array[$key]);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

run this function i hope this help..

```
function removeDuplicate($array){
    $result = array_count_values( $array );
    $dub = array();
    $answer = array();
    foreach($result as $key => $val) {
        if($val >= 3) {
            $dub[] = $key;
        }
    }
    foreach($array as $val) {
        if(!in_array($val, $dub)) {
            $answer[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function with any number of occurrences you want - by default 3

```
function removeDuplicate($arr, $x = 3){
    $new = $rem = array();
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        $new[$val]++;
        if($new[$val]>=$x){
            $rem[$val]=$new[$val];
        }
    }
    $new = array_keys(array_diff_key($new, $rem));
    return $new;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is getting correct output. just try once.

```
 $array=array(1,2,3,7,4,4,3,5,5,6,7);
 $count=count($array);
 $k=array();
 for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
 {
 if(!in_array($array[$i],$k))
 {
 $k[]=$array[$i];
 }
 }
 array_pop($k);
 print_r($k);
```

in this first $k is an empty array,after that we are inserting values into $k.

Answer (score 0):

You should use array_unique funciton.

```
<?php
    $q = array(1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1, 9);
    print_r(array_unique($q));
?>
```

Try it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Also, this will return `[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 9]` which is not what OP wanted.